# echarts4r: produce a bar plot with polar coordinates

Tags: r, echarts

I am trying to use `echarts4r`, an R interface to the popular Javascript Echarts library, to build a **bar plot within the polar coordinate system**.

The help files available indicate that this is **simply not possible**. In R, there is no coordinate-related argument in `e_bar()` (unlike `e_line()`, which does have one). Echarts documentation also states that "Polar coordinate can be used in scatter and line chart.".

And yet, **here is an example in the Echarts gallery** of exactly that plot: https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=bar-polar-real-estate.

My attempt, obviously unsuccessful, was this:

```
gen_int <- function(n, k = 10) {
  sample(as.integer(1:n), size = k, replace = TRUE)
}
library(dplyr)

dat <- tibble(id = letters[1:10],
              x = gen_int(10),
              y = gen_int(10))

library(echarts4r)

dat %>% 
    slice(1:5) %>%
    e_charts(id) %>% 
    e_polar() %>% 
    e_bar(x, coordinateSystem = list('polar'))
```

Any ideas how to do this? In `ggplot2`, it would look like this:

```
dat %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = id, y = x)) +
    geom_col() +
    coord_polar()
```

[image]

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: @JohnCoene calling for help! Thanks for the awesome library by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. We can accomplish that by slightly modifying the example in `e_polar`.

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = seq(1, 20, by = 2))

df %>% 
    e_charts(x) %>% 
    e_polar() %>% 
    e_angle_axis() %>% 
    e_radius_axis() %>% 
    e_bar(y, coordinateSystem = "polar")
```

As you can see in the example  you link there is need for polar, radius and angle axis.

Comment: By the way, the plot doesn't work for some reason if the grouping variable is of type character (which is often the case with bar plots): `df <- data.frame(x = letters[1:10], y = seq(1, 20, by = 2))`. I get an empty polar plot with no contents using exactly the same code.

Comment: OK thanks for reporting that, I had never noticed, I'll add proper support for radial bars in the next release.

Comment: Works in dev version, see `?e_angle_axis`.

Comment: Still doesn't work with `e_bar()` I'm afraid (df with letters, that is).

Comment: @Maxim.K apologies, previous way a bit hacky, fixed in dev version by properly implementing coordinate system in `e_bar`, `e_line` and `e_scatter`, also added arguments to various axis functions, demo and doc [here](https://echarts4r.john-coene.com/articles/grid.html#axis) (bottom of page). _Not change breaking_